# Objects disappear when zoomed out in Unity

Tags: unity

Ignore the palm trees here.

I have some oak-like trees when I'm zoomed in:
[image: trees]

They disappear when I zoom out:
[image: no trees]

Is this normal? Is this something to do with draw distance? How can I change this so my trees don't disappear?

The reason I ask is because my installation had a weird terrain glitch. If this isn't normal I'm going to reinstall right away because I'm always thinking 'is that a feature? Or a glitch'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm..maybe I should stop firing off questions.

Try hitting this button if you get into this situation:

Click the terrain, and in the contextual inspector, there is a refresh button (bottom right of this screen shot). Click that if you've updated your trees.
[image: inspector]

I scaled up my tree mesh because they were tiny. I scaled it up, but the billboards remained tiny ( I mean really tiny) so they can't be seem when you zoom out. When I click refresh, the billboards are re-generated from the larger resized mesh so they stop appearing to disappear